# Uniform distribution question.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In the 50-meter running final, the times are considered to be uniformly distributed between 19.5 and 30.5 seconds. There are 8 independent competitors in the finals, and that the current world record is 21.3 seconds.
Determine the probability that the loser of the race will not break the world record.

Comment: **Hint:** A slightly easier question to answer is: *What is the probability that the loser (and therefore all competitors) breaks the record?*

Answer (score 0):

> Determine the probability that the loser of the race will not break the world record

The loser? The winner, I suppose...

If this is, calculate

$$\mathbb{P}[\min(X_i)]>21.3$$

That is

$$\left(1-\frac{21.3-19,5}{21}\right)^8\approx0.488=0.49$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $N$ swimmers, $X_n \sim U[a,b]$ and the record is $x$. Thus
$$\begin{aligned}P(\min (\{X_n:n \in \{1,2,...,N\}\})<x)&=P(\cup_{n=1}^N\{X_n<x\})=\\
&=P((\cap_{n=1}^N\{X_n<x\}^c)^c)=\\
&=1-P(\cap_{n=1}^N\{X_n<x\}^c)=\\
&=1-P(\cap_{n=1}^N\{X_n\geq x\})=\\
&=1-\bigg(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\bigg)^N=\\
&\approx 0.76
\end{aligned}$$
Where I used De Morgan's laws.